# Restrict resources for tensorflow on a single GPU

Tags: docker, tensorflow, keras, gpu

I run some `tensorflow.keras` code (with the official tensorflow docker image) on my local machine with a RTX2080 GPU. Since the memory and GPU-Util is nearly maxed out the response of the machine becomes very slow. I still want to be able to work on that machine so is there a way to restrict/limit resources (similar to `nice -n10 ...` on unix)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What model are you trying to train? How big is it?

Comment: Currently something related to a ResNet (approx. 1.8 Million parameters) for singe image super-resolution. But they maybe become even larger in the future as I am still prototyping.